# Installing and starting MongoDB for PHP on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, php-mongodb, mongodb

I have installed the `mongo` extension from PECL and added it to my `php.ini` file. The extension loads when I run `phpinfo();` but shows me this error when I try to connect to the Mongo Server.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with message 'Transport
endpoint is not connected' in /var/www/mongo.php:2 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/mongo.php(2):
Mongo->__construct() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/mongo.php on line 2
```

`phpinfo();` tells me its running on localhost at the default port.

Also I installed the `mongodb_client` package for Ubuntu, which also fails to connect on the default server running when I use it from the terminal, although it can connect to the server on *MongoLab*. The PHP Script also fails to connect to the *MongoLab* server.

After reading many questions and answers on SO and other sites, I guess my MongoDB server on my computer is not turned on. All the articles tell me to go to some folder where MongoDB may be installed, but I dont have any folder in `/var/lib` or in `/usr/lib`

Please help me get this MongoDB working, I want to continue to on learn MongoDB from the **MongoDB and PHP** book by Steve Francia. The book doesn't have a good tutorial on installing MongoDB.

Thanks.

Comment: try: sudo service mongodb start

Comment: it says "mongodb: unrecognized service"

Comment: Maybe it's mongo instead of mongodb? (I'm using the version from the 10gen repo instead of the Ubuntu version.)

Comment: i tried both, it gives the same error. i think it might not have installed properly, i guess but parts are working, its DB is just not starting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Installing MongoDB (not from a package, but it'll get you started):

- Download 2.0.4 from www.mongodb.org/downloads.
- `tar zxvf mongodb-...`
- Change to the mongodb directory you just untared.
- Make a directory to hold your data:

  ```
  $ mkdir myData
  ```
- Run:

  ```
  $ bin/mongod --dbpath myData
  ```

You should see some output, then "waiting for connections on port 27017" and then it'll "freeze" waiting for you to start using it.  At that point you should be able to connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

I perfer not using the Ubuntu package, so I'd do as @kristina says MongoDB is super easy to run from the binaries ... but since you seem to prefer a package, run ...

**aptitude search mongo**

You should sen an entry for **mongo-server** ... install that.

If you don't see it, follow these directions: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

You should then be able to connect locally, this may also help you get going: http://learnmongo.com/posts/mongodb-php-install-and-connect/

Answer (score 2):

This worked on my server:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ubuntu+and+Debian+packages

I made one change to the /etc/mongodb.conf file to enable REST:

```
#enable REST
rest = true
```

GridFS works when I connect to it too (except from Node.js - but I think there's a bug in the driver I am using). 
So all in all, there isn't much I can complain about using the following:

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know mongodb php driver doesn't care how you run mongod server. The only thing matters is there should be mongod instance running and you are connecting to it on right port. So make sure you are connecting to the right port.

Just to make life with mongodb a little easier you can use binary executable from the mongodb download section. Ubuntu apt-get installation might give you some trouble.

For me I prefer downloading ready to use binary for my OS. Then I extract and put it in /op/ folder so that the mongodb executable locate in /opt/mongo/bin/

After this I add this folder to the $PATH variable so that I can run mongodb commands from anywhere. To do this I add PATH="$PATH:/opt/mongo/bin" to the .bashrc file which is in the home folder.

This method give me an easy way to upgrade, I just have to copy and replace the /opt/mongo/bin folder. And then restart the mongod servers.